# Secure copy a movie from Mac to iPad

Tags: jailbreak

I have a Mac and a jailbroken iPad. Jailbreaking is perfectly legal where I write this. I can `scp` and `rsync` to the device (i.e. I can file-transfer), how would I best transfer some movies to watch on the iPad?

- Which folder on the iPad?
- Which app on the iPad? (preferably: free)

Any combination that works without using iTunes would do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to watch with the built in iTunes Player, I would suggest [Music2iPod](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=music2ipodDp), a free app that can access any file (including videos) on a jailbroken iDevice and add it to the iTunes library. To add the video file to your device I would suggest connecting with a GUI SCP program (like Cyberduck) and transferring to the default directory (it really doesn't matter where, as long as you have read/write access and can remember it), then navigating to this with Music2iPod, which will then add the video to your iPod library for you.